# Número de archivos y directorios en un directorio de Linux, pero sólo en el segundo nivel

Tags: linux, archivo, consola, debian, línea-de-comandos

La instrucción:

`$ ls | wc -l`

nos da el número de directorios y archivos que hay en un determinado directorio sin contar los que haya dentro de los propios subdirectorios de este primer nivel, o sea, nos da el número de un modo no recursivo.

¿Cómo podría saber el número de archivos y directorios que hay sólo en el segundo nivel de ese mismo directorio? Esto es, el número de subdirectorios y archivos que hay en los subdirectorios del directorio principal, también de un modo no recursivo, sólo al nivel 2.

La instrucción:

```
$ shuf -ezn 7 directorio/*/*/* | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```

nos muestra 7 archivos o directorios elegidos aleatoriamente de entre los del segundo nivel del directorio principal. Trabaja perfectamente, pero soy incapaz de razonar un comando similar para conseguir lo que quiero.

Espero haberme explicado. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente haya otras opciones mejores, pero creo que lo he encontrado:

```
find directorio_principal/  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 | wc -l
```

me da el resultado esperado.

Espero que le ayude a alguien

Comment: Bien resuelto con mindepth y maxdepth. Nótese que podría darse el caso (extraño pero posible) de que un directorio tuviera como nombre algo que contuviera un salto de línea, en cuyo caso el contador daría un valor de más. Por ello se suele recomendar hacer `find ... -printf '.'` y luego contar los puntos